# Is it possible to describe the same style for several classes with several selectors CSS

Tags: css

Suppose I have different views. They have some common parts and some specific ones. Can I make my code clearer?

```
.View1 th, td { padding: 5px; } 
.view2 th, td { padding: 5px; }
```

I've looked through different resources but haven't found anything proper.

Something like (if it worked):

```
.View1 th, td, .View2 th, td { padding: 5px; }
```

Comment: I would suggest using sass for cleaner css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors are incorrect. It should be

```
.View1 th, .View1 td, .View2 th, .View2 td { padding: 5px; }
```

Comment: it was so simple)